# Plotting two lists in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have two lists. For e.g.: list A is `[1 2 3 2  2 1]` and list B is `[1.2 2.2 1 1 1 1]`. I want to have the unique numbers of list A on the x-axis and sum of the corresponding entries in list B. For eg: For the above example, I want to plot {(1,2.2),(2,4.2),(3,1)} as a histogram ( not a scatter plot).

My requirement involves two steps.

1. First to sum values in list B for each unique value in list A
2. Plotting these sums against the corresponding values in list A as a histogram.

Can you please help me.

Edit: 
Here is my attempt, based on the little I could understand from reading other answers on SO:

```
(def A [1 2 3 2 1])
(def B [1.2 2.3 2 1 1])
(for [x (distinct A)] (map first 
           (filter #(= (second %) x)
                   (map-indexed vector A))))
;; This gives the indices for each unique element in A
;; In this case, it gives ((0 4) (1 3) (2))
```

I am unable to figure out how to find how to get corresponding sum from list B. I tried the following but it does not work.

```
(apply nth B (map first 
           (filter #(= (second %) 1)
                   (map-indexed vector A))) )
;; In this case, it gives on the first element i.e. 1.2
```

As you can see, I am new to Clojure and functional programming languages. Can you please point me towards some examples which have solved similar problems?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
Final solution for the first task:

```
(for [x (distinct A)]     (reduce + 0.0 (map #(nth B %) (map first 
               (filter #(= (second %) x)
                       (map-indexed vector A))) )  )         )
    ;; This gives me the correct output (2.2 3.3 2.0)
```

P.S: I did not understand this concept of using `(map #(nth B%)..`. I just stumbled onto it from other examples.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @m0skit0: For the second task, I think I have to use (plot/list- plot ...). I tried `(plot/list-plot list A listC)`, where is the list C is the output of first task. I am totally cluelless about the first task.. I will be thankful if you can at least guide towards similar questions which have been answered..

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and show what code you have so far. I think the first task is relatively simple for you to at least try :)

Comment: @m0skit0: updated with my attempt.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I think the expected result list you provided is wrong, shouldn't the last element be (3 4)?

Comment: @m0skit0: Edited to reflect the same.

Comment: Ok I'm lost here, if A is [1 2 3 2  2 1] and B is [1.2 2.2 1 1 1 1], shouldn't the result be `{1 2.2, 2 4.3, 3 4}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181174/discussion-between-kasa-and-m0skit0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first task, I guess this way is a bit simpler:

```clj
(def A [1 2 3 2  2 1])
(def B [1.2 2.2 1 1 1 1])
(def C
  (reduce (partial merge-with +)
          (map hash-map A B))) ; Vector of key-values [{1 1.2} {2 2.2} ...]
; {1 2.2, 2 4.2, 3 1}
```

For the second task, there are many chart library options out there. I picked up [clj-xchart](https://hypirion.github.io/clj-xchart/examples) as an example:

```clj
(require '[com.hypirion.clj-xchart :as c])

(let [x-values (keys C)
      min-x (apply min x-values)
      max-x (apply max x-values)]
  (c/view
    (c/category-chart
      {"C" C}
      {:title "Example"
       :legend {:visible? false}
       :x-axis {:order (range min-x max-x)}
       :theme :ggplot2})))
```

And the final plot:

[image: Chart example]